# Background image icons are not with the correct dimensions (are smaller)

Tags: css

I have a full with yellow background and in this background there are some icons. And for example in large screens 1920x1080 I want to have 17 columns of icons horizontally occupying the full with of the yellow background and just 4 rows of icons.

The issue is that the icons are not with the correct dimension, are smaller, and so instead of 17 columns of icons I get more than 30 columns of icons. And instead of 4 rows I get 8 rows of icons.

Do you know how to fix this?

html:

```
<section class="container content-search">
  <div class="div">
    <h1>Title</h1>

  </div>
  <section>
```

css:

```
.content-search {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .54);
  min-height: 360px;
}

.content-search:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/cxLLc5/img22.png) 0 0 / auto 50%;
  opacity: .25;
}

.div {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/h6apm4pc/1/

Comment: Try `background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/cxLLc5/img22.png) 0 0 / auto 100%;` . Swap out the 50% to 100%. That will get you 4 rows of icons.

Comment: Thank you, now it appears only 4 rows but the icons are not with the same size of the image, the icons are still a bit smaller and so there are a lot of columns with icons.

Comment: `background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/cxLLc5/img22.png) 0 0 / 50% 100%;` . You could change the first `auto` to `50%` and play around with it, however the shapes will probably not stay proportional to the original image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with 50% 100% the images dont appear followed.